# SFML and Code::Blocks 0xc00000be

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I've just started developing with SFML 2.1 on Windows 7 using Code::Blocks as my IDE. I am using the libraries compiled for MinGW. I followed the tutorial for how to setup SFML in Code::Blocks, but I've run into an error that I've never seen before when I run the program:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00000be). Click OK to close the application.
```

So far, I've tried both statically and dynamically linking SFML to no avail. I've tried running both debug mode and release mode, which also produced the same error each time. The error occurs every time I execute the program, but no errors when I compile.

Yes, I do have libraries linked in the proper order, and yes I am using the `xxxx-s` when I link the libraries statically and `xxxx-d` for debugging, as well as `xxxx-s-d` for statically linked debug. At the time of this post, I just got the latest SFML 2.1 roughly 10 hours ago, so unless SFML has updated since, I am using the latest build. I also tried to rebuild the project, which also did not fix.

However, I did try re-arranging the libraries in a different order (`sfml-system` first, then `sfml-window`, and then `sfml-graphics`; yes I know this is in reverse order, but it was just to test) and it still produced the same error.

Source code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Works!");
    sf::CircleShape circle(50.f);
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(circle);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

*Semi-fix:* If I use SFML compiled for TDM, then the program runs with no errors. However, if I use the MinGW libraries, I get the error: `The procedure entry point__gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll`.

Comment: You might want to check that the window is open before trying to manipulate (clear, draw, display) the window.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That actually happens already (see the outermost `while()`).

Comment: Yes, but think about what happens when you close the window inside the inner (event) loop?

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're referring to. But no, that typically shouldn't matter either.

Comment: DealerNextDoor: What happens if you run the compiled program yourself rather than using the IDE? I could imagine that there's some suppressed error message that's more clear (like a missing dependency).

Comment: It works if I use the TDM libraries, but not the MinGW libraries.

Comment: To me it looks like that you are using libs compiled with a different compiler version and/or standard library version. This could potentially result in this behavior

Comment: Yes, what you're describing sounds like some problem due to mixing different versions of the runtime library files.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is compiling SFML using [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the reason for the crash, but your drawing code is inside the event loop, which shouldn't happen. You'll have that closing bracket (`}`) up before `window.clear()`.

Other than that, the problems seems to be somewhere outside the source you posted.

*Edit:*

The error message

> The procedure entry point__gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll.

usually indicates that the executable is somehow finding/loading the wrong version of the library *libstdc++-6.dll*. A reason for this could be a different version in a system directory or your application's directory.

To solve this, you'll have to track down the wrong copy being loaded. You can do this e.g. with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com). Just run the program and drag&drop your executable into it. It will then show you an explorer like tree with the specific libraries it tried to load. Locate the library file and see whether it's the correct one or not.

Comment: I actually didn't even notice that, thanks. However, it didn't make any changes to the error.

Comment: Updated my answer with something new to try.